# How to passing variables to PHP Script [POST] using C#

Tags: c#, php, vba, post, webrequest

I am using this code :

```
public void sendPostData(string url, string data)
    {
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);

        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

        Stream dataStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
    }
```

PHP for POST processing :

```
    <?php

if(@$_POST['filename'])
{
    $data = filter_var($_POST['filename'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $f = fopen($data.".txt", "w");
    fclose($f);
}
?>
```

I am calling by this :

```
sendPostData("http://127.0.0.1/csharptest/index.php", "filename=myvariablehere");
```

So, all it does is create a file name "myvariablehere" on server instead of storing value in myvariablehere which holds the data.

I Want "myvariablehere" value stored on server.

Please lil help here !

Thanks

Comment: what is the url you are getting, try inspecting element

Comment: It sounds like the code is doing exactly what it was written to do.

Comment: I am not getting any url. I just want to save variable values on server. What it does is just save my variable name and not the data inside it.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Yes It is indeed but how can I post the values of myvariable to the server and save it instead of just name of myvariable ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public static class Upload
    {
        public static byte[] Post(string uri, NameValueCollection pairs)
        {
            byte[] response = null;
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                response = client.UploadValues(uri, pairs);
            }
            return response;
        }
    }
```

and then simply call this

```
var response = Upload.Post("URL", new NameValueCollection() {
    { "fileName", "test" }, 
});
```